# Why is Java platform independent in theory and platform dependent in practice?

Tags: java, platform

I know that one of the big things about Java is that it is platform independent in the sense that you can make a Java application and have it run in Windows, Linux, Mac, and so forth, as long as you don't use libraries specific to one OS, and as long as you have a JVM installed for the appropriate OS to interpret things correctly...

However, why can't a normal computer Java program (as in a simple Hello World in Java, for Windows or Linux for example) run just the same in a mobile phone, when mobile phones also have their specific JVM installed to interpret things correctly?

Why is it necessary to change the architecture of the program in some cases, such as Android development, or use Java ME to make applications specific for some general mobile phones?

I know that there are some functions that are related to certain functionalities of the OS, that might not apply in the mobile platforms for example, such as some things related with console, input methods, and so forth, but is this really the only reason that makes things not compatible? If so, why won't a simple application that just declares and initializes an integer variable be able to run across all non-mobile and mobile platforms that have a JVM available?

I am aware of other questions that have been posted before, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420779/is-java-completely-platform-independent), but that do not focus the exact point I am aiming for here.

Comment: You answered it yourself: there are different environments -- and not all environments are equal (some are significantly less powerful and/or constrained). Even the idea of a "thread" may not transfer uniformly at all. Android doesn't even run a true JVM (it compiles to its own format).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unit of portability to look at is a *class* rather than an *application*. A class that declares and initialises an integer variable *will* run on all the platforms you describe, and many others too. They understand the same bytecode, even if they do execute it using different mechanisms ranging from bytecode interpreters, to JIT compilation, to Android's Dalvik (which translates JVM bytecode into its own instruction set).

Even if we look beyond a single integer variable, Java that uses "core" functionality *will* work on most of these devices. There's a great deal of common ground between J2ME, Android and J2SE (and particularly the latter two - J2ME was intended as a cut-down version of the standard Java APIs for devices with limited resources, so less of the standard API is available).

On a Windows/Mac/Linux system, an application is usually something that you explicitly start, use, and - when you're done - tell it to exit. Compare this with, say, an Android phone: the application might be started in response to an event occurring (perhaps an incoming SMS, or a specific type of file downloaded from the web) in which case it needs to know *how* and *why* it was started - a simple `public static main(String[] args)` just doesn't cut it. Once started, the app needs to be aware of events such as "low battery" or "entering standby mode" in order to free up resources or disable CPU-intensive features (such as GPS) that might otherwise drain the battery.

These aren't obscure functions - they're essential to a phone being useful as a phone - so all native applications must handle them.

Answer (score 5):

When Java Code is compiled a byte code(class file) is generated which is independent of the system. This byte code is fed to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) which resides in the system. Since every system has its own JVM, it doesn't matter where you compile the source code. The byte code generated by the compiler can be interpreted by any JVM of any machine. Hence it is called Platform independent Language.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Why is Java platform independent in theory and platform dependent in practice?

Remember and clear one thing that only the Java language is platform independent and try to understand the meaning of the sentence. Java is platform independent means the code you have developed using Java can be run on any machine.

When you compile the `.java` file it generates `.class` file and it contains bytecode and this bytecode is platform independent you can run it on any machine this is what about platform independency of Java language.

Now you said that it is not in practice so the reason is only Java language is platform independent, but its runtime enviroment, or JVM, is platform dependent, it is written separately for each OS. So we can say the Java language is platform independent, but its runtime environment is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

The java language is just one thing but then many other devices such as mobile phones run their own version which is usually a trimmed down version to fit on the device.  THese can also occasionally have other proprietary classes to help access the hardware (ie touchscreen).  By making separate platforms based off a main one you get much support and a tighter more efficient programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Sun micro systems has released different versions of jdk. one for windows based and another for linux/unix based. When we installed jdk with that we get jvm,jre and javac. Suppose if we write a java program in windows with intel processor which is installed with windows jdk, then the java compiler of that jdk will convert .java file to .class file which contains byte code instructions similar to assembly language code these byte code instructions can be understandable only by jvm. If we take the .class file which is generated in windows o.s and if we run in linux then the jvm of that linux machine internally rewrites your java program by using the approximate 200+ instruction sets which are developed by javasoft people and placed as part of jvm. and the .class file gets executed. So here the point is to concentrate that jdk is platform dependent but .class is not platform dependent it is platform independent because jvm only responsible for running any .class files. Every jdk's jvm internally has predefined instructions sets i.e., approx. 200+.