# Is java really platform independent ?

Tags: java, jvm, platform-independent

There are different versions of JVM for different operating systems/platforms. Which means that the people who developed it have made different interpreters for major operating systems. If at all a new OS comes today will java work on it too? So When we say platform independent are we restricting to platforms for which JVM is available or is Java actually platform independent?

Comment: If no JVM, what do you expect your bytecode to run atop of!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java completely Platform Independent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420779/is-java-completely-platform-independent)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate of that. The question you linked to makes more sense.

Comment: I have always wanted to say this: java developers do all the dog work of developing JVMs that work for various OS'es so you, end user (I actually mean developer here :P) can enjoy benefits of their work [write once, run in any JVM]

Comment: Thank you all for answering.. All of the answers are good enough, especially the "platform-dependent jvm through which platform independence is realized"

Comment: Of course there should be VM support. How do you think of "platform independent"? It doesn't mean it must support every platform. And it is obviously impossible. In addition, it is java execution file (.class, byte code) which is platform independent, because it runs in JVM, not everything.

Comment: From the answers below I can conclude that java is platform independent because JVM is written for all the OS... Please correct if I am wrong. 
If yes, then what difference does it make with the languages that says it is not platform dependent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly Java cannot run on a platform that doesn't have a JVM. So in the most literal sense of the word, Java isn't platform independent. But at the same time, your definition of platform independence isn't useful. No possible language could ever be truly platform independent, because some aspect of the platform would need to be able to parse the language. And given all possible platforms, some necessarily won't be able to parse it.

So, given the fact that many, many platforms run a JVM, and that Java code can be run on any JVM with the same meaning, Java is platform-dependent.

Comment: *"run on any JVM"* => see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420779/is-java-completely-platform-independent

Comment: Well obviously the parts that exploit features specific to the OS are going to be dependent on the OS. This doesn't mean Java isn't platform independent, it means that platform's behaviours are different.

Answer (score 7):

You're conflating several distinct things here.

It is the *Java Programming Language* that is platform independent, and, by extension, any program written in it.

The JVM itself is not platform independent: it is the platform-dependent means via which platform-independence of the language is realized.

Answer (score 2):

With Java, platform independence only refers to the fact that if you write your code correctly, the resulting compiled code should run unchanged and identically on any platform that supports the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously without a JVM you have no chance of executing bytecode.  This question got me wondering how difficult it actually is to port the JVM to a new platform though.  [Wpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot#Supported_platforms) has (re the HotSpot VM):

> Ports are also available by third parties for Mac OS X and various
>   other Unix operating systems. Several different hardware architectures
>   are supported, including x86, PowerPC, and SPARC (Solaris only).
>
> Porting HotSpot is difficult because the code, while primarily written
>   in C++, contains a lot of assembly language. To remedy this, the
>   IcedTea project has developed a generic port of the HotSpot
>   interpreter called zero-assembler Hotspot (or zero), with almost no
>   assembly code. This port is intended for easy adaptation of the
>   interpreter component of HotSpot to any Linux processor architecture.
>   The code of zero-assembler Hotspot is used for all the non-x86 ports
>   of HotSpot (PPC, IA64, S390 and ARM) since version 1.6.
>
> Gary Benson, an IcedTea developer, developed a platform-independent
>   Just-in-time compiler called Shark for HotSpot, using LLVM, to
>   complement zero.

Answer (score 2):

There are different aspects which needs to be considered :

**JVM** specification is not very strict on platform independence, like it doesn't say how you should implement **garbage collection**. 
So companies are free to have some component of **JVM** as platform dependent for optimizing performance. So **JVM** which executes the compiled code is not platform independent. You need JVM specific to that platform i.e. windows JVM, linux JVM, Mac OS JVM etc and there are different implementations of JVM for the same platform.

But **Java API**, **Java Language** and **Java Compiler** are platform independent.

Comment: How you implement garbage collection has nothing to do with platform independence.

Comment: @EJP agree with you as long as NONE of component/module of GC is implemented based on platform on which it runs. As per my knowledge, GC implementation is one of the area (of JVM) where implemenators write platform specific code to optimize GC process.

Answer (score 1):

In short:
Without JVM, you can not interpret the java code on any platform. JVM is a platform-dependent.
So if a new OS comes today,the java code wont run.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that Java is completely platform independent.

Because:

1. Threading schedule time slices of work depend upon processor, OS and the platform.
2. AWT Graphics change as per the output devices changes so it shows platform dependency.